# Git commit and push issue in Jenkins multibranch pipeline

Tags: .net, git, jenkins-pipeline, multibranch-pipeline

I'm working on a multibranch pipeline in Jenkins for building a .Net application and creating ms test results using msbuild on a windows server. I've written a jenkinsfile for the same.

Now the issue is, I need to commit and push the mstest results file to the same branch on git. I've tried to do the same using 'bat' in jenkinsfile, but it gives me `Detached head state`. Below is the jenkinsfile configuration:-

```
node ('windows') {


stage 'Checkout'

        checkout scm

    stage 'Build'

         bat '"Path to MSBuild.exe" ProjectFile.proj'

         bat '"Path to git.exe" add mstest/output.trx'
         bat '"Path to git.exe" commit -am "adding test results"'
         bat '"Path to git.exe" push origin Develop'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The call `checkout scm` always checks out a specific commit (latest commit on the branch from the time the `Jenkinsfile` was loaded) and results in a detached HEAD state.

If you want to checkout a specific branch and later commit changes to it, you could use git directly, which in your case may look like that:

`bat "<path-to-git.exe> checkout ${env.BRANCH_NAME}"`

Obviously, in case someone else pushes to that branch after the checkout, but before jenkins pushes the test results, this approach might lead to unexpected behavior. 
Note, that `env.BRANCH_NAME` is a build variable from Jenkins multibranch projects which gives you the name of the branch for which your pipeline is running.